# JPA inheritance and bidirectional OneToMany relation in child

Tags: jpa, inheritance, eclipselink, bidirectional

I'm trying to map an association one-to-many to an entity that is map with `@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)` but I've a validation exception when my application is loading :

> Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7250] (Eclipse Persistence
>   Services 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd):
>   org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException Exception
>
> Description: [class model.item.weapon.WeaponStat] uses a non-entity
>   [class item.weapon.Weapon] as target entity in the relationship
>   attribute [field weapon].

Here the base class :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ITEMS")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "SYSTYPE", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.INTEGER)
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "0")
public class Item implements Serializable {...
```

The class `Weapon` that inherits from `Item` :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "WEAPONS")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "ITEM_ID")
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "3")
public class Weapon extends Item {...
```

`Weapon` contains `OneToMany` attribute:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "weapon")
private List<WeaponStat> stats;
```

And `WeaponStat`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "WEAPON_STATS")
public class WeaponStat implements Serializable {...
[...code...]
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "WEAPON_ID")
private Weapon weapon;
[...code...]
```

Someone has an idea?

Comment: Is Weapon correctly listed with all the other entities in the persistence.xml file? Is it annotated with the right javax.persistence.Entity annotation?

Comment: I actually use `<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>` in my persistence.xml. If I manually specify all entities with  `<class>...</class>` the problem is the same.

Yes imports are correct.

Comment: You cant make it 
private Weapon weapon; => private Item weapon; I know its not always practical but having different members on Weapon than on Item violates LSP https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle

Comment: Thank you, the problem was indeed caused by that !

But :(

`Exception Description: Missing class for indicator field value [3] of type [class java.lang.Integer].
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(model.item.Item --> [DatabaseTable(ITEMS)])` when I try to access to a `Weapon`. If i access to a simple `Item` everything is ok...

Comment: Why do you combine Inheritance Type JOINED and Discriminator?

Comment: In documentation : [link](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Inheritance#Joined_Table_Inheritance)

Answer (score 0):

I used the following:

```
@Entity
@Configuration
class Parent()
{
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(nullable = true)
    private Set<Child> children;
    ...
}

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Child
{
 ...
}

@Entity
public class NaughtyChild extends Child
{
...
}
```

This was using Hibernate but hope it helps. Note that this is an odd configuration and not recommended by Hibernate at least due to non optimized queries that are generated but that is specific to Hibernate. I cant speak to EclipseLink.

Comment: Same problem :(

 `@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "weapon")`
`@JoinColumn(nullable = true)`
`private List<WeaponStat> stats;`